# Cron doesn't run sh script

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I have a simple script that works when I manually put it into the `~/` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/python/current/env
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
cd /opt/python/current/app
scrapy crawl myspider
deactivate
exit 0
```

Since EBS will delete the script and crontab eventually, I need to create a  `config` file in .ebextensions.

So I've created `cron-linux.config`

But I can't make it work. It doesn't do anything (I should see changes in a database).

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/crawl":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * *  /usr/local/bin/crawl.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/crawl.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: ec2-user
        group: ec2-user
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            source /opt/python/current/env
            source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
            cd /opt/python/current/app
            scrapy crawl myspider
            deactivate
            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/crawl.bak"
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Even when I do `eb logs > log.txt` and check the file, there is no such word like 'crawl', 'cron' etc...

**EDIT**

I can even manually run the script: `[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx ~]$ /usr/local/bin/crawl.sh` 
And I see that it works. Just the cron doesn't work.

Comment: That's pretty much verbatim what https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/ says ... did you do the second part, too?  `Create an application source bundle` ?

Comment: @tink I use `awsebcli` so `eb deploy` should be enough.

Comment: The problem was (probably) that I didn't write "root" between the schedule and a command. Now it works.

Comment: It sounds like you should put that comment as an answer for it.